# How to get reference of components generated dynamically

Tags: angular

How can we get the reference of components which we generated dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver`?

Additional Note:

- I have a component **reusable-component**, we have created 4 **reusable-component** (using 
  ComponentFactoryResolver), and appended to a container. Each component has a unique id
- on button click I need to call a function of each
- how can we access each component and call its function in a button click

### I Tried

To get element -- `this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#wid_' + i)`. But this will give html element only, so we can't call its function or update its property

Comment: ViewChildren, perhaps?

Comment: When you are using ComponentFactoryResolver it return a ComponentFactory that will return a ComponentRef where you can access component instance. I suggest keep a map id => ComponentRef